Is there a natural topology for subsets of a fixed topological space?
This question is an extension/clarification of the question: Is there a natural topology for sets of topological spaces?
The Hausdorff distance assigns a distance to any two subspaces $X, Y$ of a fixed metric space $M$. I am interested in the topological analog of this distance.
Question: is a natural topological structure on the set of subspaces of a fixed topological space $M$?
Note that there are no set-theoretic issues since the collection of subsets of a given set form a set.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertopology

You could identify every subset of $X$ with its characteristic function $X\to \mathbb 2$, and put on $P(X)$ the compact open topology of this set of mappings.

@PietroMajer Indeed one could do that but since there aren't that many topologies on 2, this would basically be saying that an open subset of $P(X)$ consists of subsets of X that agree on various compacts. This seems quite restrictive and doesn't really generalize the Hausdorff distance.

I'm currently writing a chapter on exactly this, but it will take a long while until everything is done. Here's a preliminary version.

I also recommend this book and this paper, both of which talk about the Vietoris topology, one of the more common topologies on sets of subsets, on all of $\mathcal{P}(X)$, rather than only on the set $\mathrm{Cld}(X)$ of closed subspaces of $X$.
